# Get specific data from GitHub API url via Ansible?

Tags: github, ansible, uri

I try to get `browser_download_url` from https://api.github.com/repos/LIMXTEC/BitCore/releases/latest which contains `gnu_no-wallet.tar.gz`

I'm really new with Ansible and try to understand how I can do it the easiest way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some tips for your future question, and to avoid downvotes: show at least what you have tried so far, we tend not to be a *"please write me this code"* service.

Comment: Thank you will pay attention in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you are looking for with the module [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) and, from its results using [`register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables), use a combination of a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) and a [`when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) to pinpoint the value you are looking for.

With the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - uri: 
        url: https://api.github.com/repos/LIMXTEC/BitCore/releases/latest
      register: github_call
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.browser_download_url }}"
      loop: "{{ github_call.json.assets }}"
      when: "'gnu_no-wallet.tar.gz' in item.browser_download_url"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

You will get the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [uri] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-0.90.9.7-win32-setup.exe) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-0.90.9.7-win64-setup.exe) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-qt-win32.exe) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-qt-win64.exe) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-win32-daemon.zip) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-win64-daemon.zip) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-x86_64-linux-gnu_no-wallet.tar.gz) => {
    "msg": "https://github.com/LIMXTEC/BitCore/releases/download/0.90.9.7/bitcore-x86_64-linux-gnu_no-wallet.tar.gz"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-x86_64-linux-gnu_qt5-dev.tar.gz) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bitcore-x86_64-linux-gnu_qt5_with-libs.tar.gz) 

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help and you explanation regarding my future postings.
I tried your code, bude I get this error:

```ERROR! 'loop_control' is not a valid attribute for a Task

The error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/api.yaml': line 9, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - debug:
      ^ here```

What's wrong?

Comment: You probably have an identation issue. Mind that, as in Python, in YAML, a wrong indentation changes the meaning of the different elements.

Comment: I just copied your code and pasted it in my yaml file, so all identations are also copied from your code.

Comment: What's you version of Ansible? Otherwise, just remove `loop_control` and `label`, those are just to reduce the output that might otherwise be cluttered

Comment: ansible 2.0.0.2

Comment: okay, updated Ansible to 2.9, is working now. Sorry, my fault! Thank you very much for your time and your help :)